# Trying to block-sleep in some js/node code using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given the following code *which I run in the command line with `node fileName.js`* it seems to run *all* the items in the loop and THEN sleep at the end ... sorta like it's all running parallel or something.

I would like the code to block/pause during the `setTimeout` instead of just running the function AFTER the setTimeout is complete. Or, use a different method if `setTimeout` is the incorrect one, in this use case.

```
const removeUsers = async () => {
    const users = await db.getUsers(); // returns 32 users.

    // Split the users up into an array, with 2 users in each 'slot'.
    var arrays = [], size = 2;
    while (users.length > 0) {
        arrays.push(users.splice(0, size));
    }

    // Now, for each slot, delete the 2 users then pause for 1 sec.
    arrays.forEach(a => {
        console.log(++counter;);

        // Delete 2x users.
        a.forEach(async u => {
            console.log('Deleting User: ' + u.id);
            await 3rdPartyApi.deleteUser({id: u.id});
        });

        // Now pause for a second.
        // Why? 3rd party api has a 2 hits/sec rate throttling.
        setTimeout(function () { console.log('Sleeping for 1 sec'); }, 1000);
    });
}
```

and the logs are like this..

```
1.
Deleting User: 1
Deleting User: 2
2.
Deleting User: 3
Deleting User: 4
3.
...
(sleep for 1 sec)
(sleep for 1 sec)
(sleep for 1 sec)
...
end.
```

See how the sleep doesn't feel like it blocks.. it just fires off a sleep command which then gets handled after a sec...

This is what I'm really after...

```
1.
Deleting User: 1
Deleting User: 2
(sleep for 1 sec)
2.
Deleting User: 3
Deleting User: 4
(sleep for 1 sec).
3.
...
end.
```

Comment: in these situations, i like to build an array of objects that the requests consumes,then make a next() function that  pop()s the stack and makes a ajax call and setTimeout's itself (next()), or "renders" the completed status.

Answer (score 1):

This calls a bunch of `async` functions. They each return a promise (`async` functions always return promises), and those promises are discarded, because `Array#forEach` doesn’t do anything with the return value of the function it’s passed.

```
a.forEach(async u => {
    console.log('Deleting User: ' + u.id);
    await 3rdPartyApi.deleteUser({id: u.id});
});
```

This starts a timer and doesn’t even attempt to wait for it.

```
setTimeout(function () { console.log('Sleeping for 1 sec'); }, 1000);
```

Split off the timer into a function that returns a promise resolving in the appropriate amount of time (available as `Promise.delay` if you’re using Bluebird, which you should be):

```
const delay = ms =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
```

and keep everything in one `async` function so you’re not discarding any promises:

```
function* chunk(array, size) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length;) {
        yield array.slice(i, i += size);
    }
}

const removeUsers = async () => {
    const users = await db.getUsers(); // returns 32 users.

    for (const a of chunk(users, 2)) {
        console.log(++counter);

        // Delete 2x users.
        for (const u of a) {
            console.log('Deleting User: ' + u.id);
            await ThirdPartyApi.deleteUser({id: u.id});
        }

        console.log('Sleeping for 1 sec');
        await delay(1000);
    }
};
```

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/xT0BKhunZXlEsnpz7q/giphy.gif Thank you !!!!